# Sending a request from django to itself

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that contains a second, third-party Django app. In one of my views, I need to query a view from the other app (within the same Django project).

Currently, it works something like this:

```py
import requests
def my_view(request):
   data = requests.get('http://localhost/foo/bar').json()
   # mangle data
   return some_response
```

Is there a clean way to send the request without going all the way through DNS and the webserver and just go directly to the other app's view (ideally going through the middleware as well of course)

Comment: If its the same django app then it'd be slower to make a request to itself than it would just to call a python function directly

Comment: You could use the RequestFactory to create a request and then send it directly to the view function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory

At least that way you don't have any network overhead.

Comment: @samfrances that skips out the middleware

Comment: `localhost` request does not use DNS.   And If you do need to to use a real url, then just add it to `/etc/hosts` to avoid DNS lookup.

Answer (score 1):

A Django view function accepts a request and returns a response object. There is no reason that a view cannot invoke another view by constructing a request (or cloning or passing its own)  and interpreting the response. (c.f. the testing framework).

Of course, if the other view has undesirable side-effects, then the controlling view will have to unwind them. Working within a transaction should allow it to delve in the results of the view it invoked, and then abort  the transaction and perform its own.

Comment: I am aware of that, and the side effects are (in this case) very much desired. However, I'd prefer going through the routing (urls) as well, as the other app doesn't have a "plain" view function (it's a graphql/grapene app).

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib as shown below

```
import urllib, urllib3, urllib.request
            url = "http://abcd.com" # API URL
            postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8") 
            req = urllib.request.Request(url)

            with urllib.request.urlopen(req, data=postdata) as response:
                resp = response.read()
                print(resp)
```

Comment: This is what I'm already doing (using requests). The question is more about how to avoid that HTTP call and stay completely within Django

Comment: `urllib.request` is a *harder to use* HTTP API, with the documentation recommending you use `requests` instead. *Telling someone to not use requests* is not a helpful solution here, since `requests` can actually do *more*. Using `urllib.request` doesn't help someone who is trying to **not make an HTTP request in the first place**. And why import `urllib3` and then not use it?